# How to use a CSS transition in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, css, css-transitions, linear-gradients

I am using JavaScript to change the colors on a webpage. It randomly chooses colors from an array to create a gradient and changes those colors every few seconds.

Right now the background changes abruptly. I want the background-color to change with a transition.
I tried `BodyColor.style.transition ~`  but it did not work.

```js
const colors = [
  "#ff5e57",
  "#d2dae2",
  "#485460",
  "#ffa801",
  "#ffd32a",
  "#ff3f34"
];

const BodyColor = document.querySelector("body");

function randomNum(array) {
  if (!array) {
    var array = [];
  }
  let n = Math.floor(Math.random() * 18);
  if (array.length < 2 && array.indexOf(n) < 0) {
    array.push(n);
    return randomNum(array);
  } else {
    return array;
  }
}

function changeBackground() {
  BodyColor.style.background = `linear-gradient(to right, ${colors[randomNum()[0]]},${colors[randomNum()[1]]})`;
}

changeBackground();
setInterval(changeBackground, 2000);
```

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean by "not working"? Also, are you sure that `changeBackground()` is being called? I would put an `alert("hello world!");` in your `changeBackground()` and see if that pops up on page refresh or whatever triggers the function call.

Comment: A now deleted answer pointed to this blog post about [transitioning gradients](https://keithjgrant.com/posts/2017/07/transitioning-gradients/). Can you clarify whether your issue is that you wanted a smooth transition in the gradient? Because right now your question says it isn't working but the background *is* changing, it's just doing it abruptly.

Comment: I want to add transition in `changeBackground()` but I dont know how to do....

Answer (score 1):

As Alexis88 pointed out, you can't use a transition directly, and the link he indicated uses an opacity change to place that transition.

I adapted this solution by replacing the css `::hover` by adding a class.

To change the value of the colors I used css variables

the transition takes place in 2 stages
1- random choice of the 2 colors making up the new gradient then addition of the css class
2- once the transition is completed but in place of these 2 default colors and deletion of the class

The slightly complicated side is the random choice of 2 colors, the number of possible combinations here is 6 x 5, for 2 colors. Yes, this is not a pickaxe system. I pushed this choice by rejecting any combinations over a history of 3 periods, and also imposed the systematic change of the 2 colors

some useful links:
-[IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE)
-[Arrow function expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)
-[Using CSS variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties)
-[transitionend event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/transitionend_event)

```js
const BgChange =(_=>  // IIFE code
  {
  const
    classTransit = 'newBG'
  , colors       = [ '#ff5e57', '#d2dae2', '#485460', '#ffa801', '#ffd32a', '#ff3f34' ]
  , subSet       = colors.length -1
  , combinations = colors.length * subSet
  , choices = 
    { prevs : [-1,-1,-1]  // previous BG choices 
    , i_p   : 0           // index on
    , i_pMx : 3           // choices.prevs.length
    , last  : { c1: -1, c2: -1 }
    , curr  : { c1:  0, c2:  0 }
    }
  , newColors =_=>
    {
    let x;
    do {
      x  = Math.floor(Math.random() *combinations)
      choices.curr.c1 = Math.floor(x / subSet)
      choices.curr.c2 = x % subSet
      if (choices.curr.c2 >= choices.curr.c1) choices.curr.c2++
    } while
      ( choices.prevs.includes(x)
      || choices.last.c1 === choices.curr.c1
      || choices.last.c2 === choices.curr.c2
      )
    choices.prevs[choices.i_p++] = x
    choices.i_p %= choices.i_pMx
    }
    ;
  // -----   init first BG
  newColors()
  for ( let color in choices.curr ) 
    document.body.style.setProperty(`--${color}`, colors[choices.curr[color]]);
  Object.assign( choices.last, choices.curr )

  document.body.addEventListener('transitionend', _=>
    {
    if (document.body.classList.contains(classTransit))
      {
      for ( let color in choices.curr ) 
        document.body.style.setProperty(`--${color}`, colors[choices.curr[color]]);
      document.body.classList.remove(classTransit)
      }
    });

  return _=>  // transition BG function
    {
    newColors()
    for ( let color in choices.curr ) 
        document.body.style.setProperty(`--${color}a`, colors[choices.curr[color]]);
    document.body.classList.add(classTransit)
    }
  })()

// here we are!
setInterval( BgChange, 4000)
```

```css
body {
  --c1   : #ffffff;
  --c1a  : #ffffff;
  --c2   : #ffffff;
  --c2a  : #ffffff;
  margin           : 0;
  width            : 100vw;
  height           : 100vh;
  position         : relative;
  background-image : linear-gradient( to right, var(--c1), var(--c2) );
  z-index          : 1;
  }
body::before {
  position         : absolute;
  content          : '';
  top              : 0;
  right            : 0;
  bottom           : 0;
  left             : 0;
  background-image : linear-gradient( to right, var(--c1a), var(--c2a) );
  z-index          : -1;
  transition       : opacity 0.5s linear;
  opacity          : 0;
  }
body.newBG::before {
  opacity          : 1;
  }
```

Comment: @Alexis88 thanks :)